# PageSpeed Insights API limits

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I've been searching everywhere but I couldn't find the answer to the following questions.

What are the limits? How many requests per day?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've logged into my Google Developers Console and I can see that I have a quota of 25,000  requests a day. Once you have signed up for the service, you can also apply for an higher quota if necessary!

[image: Google PageSpeed API]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately Google is not taking more applications. They say that: "Page Speed Online API quota request
The form "Page Speed Online API quota request" is no longer accepting responses.

Try contacting the owner of the form if you think this is a mistake."

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2020 this is now 400 queries per 100 seconds and 25.000 queries per day.

Even though it says that you can request more quota, it doesn't look like you can. At least I couldn't find a way to do that.

[image: PageSpeed Insights API Quota]

Answer (score 0):

> Google imposes a quota limit on PageSpeed Insights API usage. The
>   current limit (as of September, 2015) is 25,000 requests / day and 1
>   requests / second. The default pause is 1 second between sending
>   requests to Google to avoid exceeding quota.

Taken from following

https://nodepit.com/node/com.mmiagency.knime.nodes.google.pagespeed.GooglePageSpeedNodeFactory