# Page Speed Insights Quota

Tags: pagespeed, google-apis-explorer

It's possible to extend the quota of 25,000 request for **Google Page Speed Insights**? I can't find any documentation about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow duplicate with the below question, I think.
[PageSpeed Insights API limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122041/pagespeed-insights-api-limits)
As for my experience, it will take within 1 week for the request to be proved.
[image: you can request for more quota here]