# Google Apps Script limitation to Extract data from web page using Cheerio Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, cheerio

Continuing my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673558/extracting-data-from-web-page-using-cheerio-library/72674373?noredirect=1#comment128513878_72674373),  `@Tanaike` proposed a solution to extract performance score from the following [page](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fruitbliss.com%2F):

[image]

This is the code snippet to get around it:

```
function CheckPageSpeed(url) {
 
  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.


  const apiEndpoint = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?key=${apiKey}&url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&category=performance`;
  const strategy = ["mobile"];
  
  
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(strategy.map(e => ({ url: `${apiEndpoint}&strategy=${e}`, muteHttpExceptions: true })));
  
  

  
  const values = res.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      const obj = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
        o[strategy[i]] = obj.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100;
  
    } else {
      o[strategy[i]] = null;
    }
    return o;
  }, {});
 
  return values.mobile;
  
}
```

As I am using it in `Google sheets as custom formula`, sometimes it takes so much time that the sheet throws the following error:
[image]

Is there any way that we can counter this error so that it starts calculating the score again instead of throwing an error? Thank you.

Comment: When I saw your showing script, `CheckPageSpeed()` has no arguments and no returned values. But, in your showing Spreadsheet image, it seems that a custom function of `=CheckPageSpeed(argument)` is used. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from that of your showing Spreadsheet image. How about this?

Comment: please check it now, I have updated the script, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a workaround for your situation. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

From your showing image, your error of `Exceed maximum execution time` and your updated script, in this case, it is considered that the execution time of the script is over 30 seconds. (In the current stage, the maximum execution time of the custom function is 30 seconds. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)) In this case, when the error of `Exceed maximum execution time` occurs, unfortunately, this cannot be used as the trigger. And also, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp` cannot be stopped over time. And, for example, even when all URLs are retrieved and each value is retrieved from the API, I'm not sure whether the processing time is over 6 minutes. I'm worried about this.

From the above situation, how about manually rerunning only the custom functions which occur the error?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). How about executing this function by a button on Spreadsheet and/or the custom menu?

```js
function reCalculation() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.
  const formula = "=CheckPageSpeed"; // Please set the function name of your custom function.
  const dummy = "=sample";
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const requests = values.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
    if (a == "#ERROR!") {
      ar.push({ findReplace: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i, endRowIndex: i + 1, startColumnIndex: 1, endColumnIndex: 2 }, find: `^${formula}`, replacement: dummy, includeFormulas: true, searchByRegex: true } }); // Modified
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  requests.forEach(r => {
    r.findReplace.find = dummy;
    r.findReplace.replacement = formula;
    r.findReplace.searchByRegex = false;
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, only the cells of `#ERROR!` in the column "B" are recalculated.

#### Note:

- I thought that in this case, this function might be able to be executed by the time-driven trigger. But, in that case, it might affect the quotas (maximum execution time is 90 minutes/day) of the time-driven trigger. So, in this answer, I proposed to run this function using manual operation.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)

### Added:

For example, in your situation, how about directly requesting the API endpoint using `fetchAll` method? The sample script is as follows. In this case, the URLs are retrieved from the column "A" and the values are retrieved and put to the column "C" in your sample Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please set your API key. And, please run this script with the script editor. By this, the values are retrieved using the API.

```js
function reCalculation2() {
  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const requests = values.map(([url]) => {
    const apiEndpoint = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?key=${apiKey}&url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&category=performance&strategy=mobile`;
    return { url: apiEndpoint, muteHttpExceptions: true };
  });
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  const v = res.map(r => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      const obj = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
      return [obj.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100];
    }
    return [null];
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 3, v.length).setValues(v);
}
```

- In this case, `fetchAll` method is used. By this, I thought that the error of `Exceeded maximum execution` might be able to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, when I ran this code I encountered the following error:

`Sheets is not defined`.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. About `Thank you for your solution, when I ran this code I encountered the following error: Sheets is not defined.`, I think that the reason of your current issue is due to that Sheets API is not enabled with Advanced Google services. Could you please confirm it again?

Comment: Thank you, I apologize as I missed your instruction about enabling it. Script ran successfully, but the `#Error` cells didn't recalculate the formula.

Comment: @Roomi Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, when you modify `ar.push({ findReplace: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i, endRowIndex: i + 1, startColumnIndex: 2, endColumnIndex: 3 }, find: `^${formula}`, replacement: dummy, includeFormulas: true, searchByRegex: true } });` to `ar.push({ findReplace: { range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i, endRowIndex: i + 1, startColumnIndex: 1, endColumnIndex: 2 }, find: `^${formula}`, replacement: dummy, includeFormulas: true, searchByRegex: true } });` and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Roomi For `Thank you, I apologize as I missed your instruction about enabling it. Script ran successfully, but the #Error cells didn't recalculate the formula. `, I updated my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If the same issue occurs, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you, the Same issue. Here is the sheet link for your reference:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xt6ueBvSwIfXO-GzhUk_018TvF0Jfj1jMTvVQDSn4yc/edit#gid=1759198411`

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. From `the Same issue`, when I run the script using my sample script, the cells of `#ERROR!` are recalculated. So, I cannot replicate `but the #Error cells didn't recalculate the formula.`. Can I ask you about the detailed method for correctly replicating `but the #Error cells didn't recalculate the formula.`?

Comment: Thank you, the script changes the cell's value from `#ERROR!` to `Loading`. I think it is working now.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `So, I ran your script manually from the script editor and the cells with #ERROR! were not changed to anything, they just remain the same`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script to your Spreadsheet, the cells of `#ERROR!` are recalculated. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, as one more workaround, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?